# It's good practice to "embed" keycloak into spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

We are going to develop an application using spring boot + keycloak and planning to embed keycloak into the same application. In few deployments we might need to create clustering also and we will not wish to create multiple nodes for the keycloak since we want authorization from any one keycloak server only.

1st : Is it possible ?
2nd : It will be a good practice to do so ?

Comment: Did you find a suitable answer ?